# Getting "Task is not yet complete" error when uploading file to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

So I made an application where the user can provide data in the form of images and descriptions, then this data will be uploaded to Firestore, and the images will be saved to Firebase Storage. After running, the image is successfully saved to Firebase Storage but the data in Firestore does not change.
I use this code:

```
val filePathAndName="product_images/"+""+timeStamp

val storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(filePathAndName)

val uploadTask= storageReference.putFile(image_Uri)
    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {  taskSnapShot->
        val uriTask=taskSnapShot.storage.downloadUrl

        val downloadImageUri=uriTask.result

        val item = Item(
            ""+firebaseAuth.uid,
            timeStamp,
            kategori,
            berat_sampah.toDouble(),
            deskripsi,
            ""+downloadImageUri,
        )
        FirestoreClass().addItem(this@AddProductActivity, FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID(),item)
```

In my FirestoreClass:

```
class FirestoreClass {

    private  val mFireStore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    fun addItem(activity: AddProductActivity, userId: String, itemInfo: Item){
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS).document(userId)
            .collection(Constants.PRODUCT).document(itemInfo.productId)
            .set(itemInfo, SetOptions.merge())
    }

    fun getCurrentUserID(): String{
        val currentUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        var currentUserID=""
        if(currentUser!=null)
        {
            currentUserID=currentUser.uid
        }
        return currentUserID
    }

    }
```

It seems that after the image is uploaded in Storage, the activity is forcibly closed. And this error is displayed:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.b1, PID: 15693
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source:121)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.example.b1.activity.AddProductActivity$addProduct$1.onSuccess(AddProductActivity.kt:163)
        at com.example.b1.activity.AddProductActivity$addProduct$1.onSuccess(AddProductActivity.kt:35)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$new$0$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:123)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$xlHsb5OfSRp-di5vg8sdDdXsCO4.raise(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.TaskListenerImpl.lambda$onInternalStateChanged$2$TaskListenerImpl(TaskListenerImpl.java:90)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$TaskListenerImpl$S8elBxPWPDCBbbHv0Z6yA1jvX68.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

why is this happening? and what is the Task that not yet completed mentioned in Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be coming from here:

```
val uriTask=taskSnapShot.storage.downloadUrl

val downloadImageUri=uriTask.result
```

The `downloadUrl` property is actually an asynchronous method call. So you can't just get the result from the task, but have to wait for it - similar to what you already do for `putFile()`.

Something like this:

```
taskSnapShot.storage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { task ->
    val downloadUri = task.result
    // Use the downloadUri here
}
```

Also see the example in the Firebase documentation on [getting the download URL for an uploaded file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url).